# Azure Web App of nodejs application loads blank screen after deployment

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to learn to use the azure web app services to deploy a MEAN stack application.

I connected Web App deployments to a git repo and clicked deploy, which it appears to have done successfully.

When I load the webapp url in a browser, its a blank white screen.

How do I troubleshoot this scenario?

Comment: Can you post the actual app.js or server.js?

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the correct ports are opened.

Good luck!

Comment: This is a Web App, not a VM. No ports to worry about :)

Answer (score 1):

There are various steps for debugging Node.js web apps on Azure Web Apps here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug/

Start off by enabling logging in your IISNode.yml file by setting loggingEnabled: true and devErrorsEnabled: true and seeing what the logs say.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use KUDU to debug Node.js application on Azure Web Site (currently named Web Apps). I doubted this might because the root directory was incorrect, i.e. your website should be started under `~/your_project/app` but in Azure it was launched under `~/your_project`.

Here is a doc for KUDU. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx