# node web app in azure is blank

Tags: node.js, azure, express, deployment

I'm new to node and express but I'm having an issue when I host my node  web app in windows azure which by the way works completely fine on localhost. I just get a blank white screen.

this is my:
**server.js**

```
var root = require('root');
var github = require('github-auth');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

// var app = root();
var app = express();


var gh = github('clientid', 'clientsecret, {
  organization: 'my-org',
  team: 'my-team',
  autologin: true // This automatically redirects you to github to login
});


app.get('/login', gh.login);


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));


app.all('*', gh.authenticate);
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.github) return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/login.html');


  if (!req.github.authenticated) res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/kickout.html'));
  next();
});

app.get('/main',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/main.html'));
});

app.get('/about',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile('/kickout.html');
});

app.listen(3000);

console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011063/azure-web-app-of-nodejs-application-loads-blank-screen-after-deployment  this didn't help me at all

Comment: you should check if the deployment did happen perfectly, can you please share the deployment log, this is how you get it from kudu http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2014/04/01/get-windows-azure-web-site-deployment-logs-with-kudu.aspx

Comment: Are you hosting your app on a WebRole, or on an Azure App service WebApp?

Comment: I am hosting it on an azure WebApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When hosting Node.js apps via Azure Web Apps, you need to modify your port initialization as shown in the following simplified sample:

```
var http = require('http'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);
```

When running locally, the literal port will be used (e.g. `1337` above), but when running in Azure a port will be assigned to `process.env.port` by the hosting platform and that will be used. You can find a complete walkthrough on deploying a Node.js app [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-develop-deploy-mac/). When running in a WebApp, a technology called **IIS Node** is used to run your Node app. More details on that can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/14/windows-azure-websites-node-js.aspx).

Comment: thanks alot, all I had to do was configure my port that azure will assign to `process.env.port`

Answer (score 1):

Node.js application running on Azure Web Apps Service, is hosted on IIS handled mapping via IISNode, which gives a `Named Pipe` to receive the incoming requests, not a TCP port like you would use when running locally.

This `Named Pipe` has been defined as the `port` in Node.js runtime on Azure Web Apps. You can define the `port` in your app link: `process.env.PORT || 3000`, with which your app can run on Azure or locally.

And you may check whether there is a file `web.config` in your root directory, which is the configurations of IIS of your application. It should have the similar content:

```
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
               <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>

                    <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                    </rule>

               </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options -->
        <!--<iisnode      
          node_env="%node_env%"
          nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;"
          nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
          maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
          maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="3"
          namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="2000"      
          maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
          maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
          asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
          initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
          maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
          watchedFiles="*.js"
          uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"      
          gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
          loggingEnabled="true"
          logDirectoryNameSuffix="logs"
          debuggingEnabled="true"
          debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
          debuggerPathSegment="debug"
          maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
          appendToExistingLog="false"
          logFileFlushInterval="5000"
          devErrorsEnabled="true"
          flushResponse="false"      
          enableXFF="false"
          promoteServerVars=""
         />-->
        <iisnode watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.jade"/>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```